# React image file to canvas and then convert to base64

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this function on file select:

```
uploadFile(e) {
   var ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
   var img = new Image();

   img.src = url;
   img.onload = function () {    
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 600,
            0, 0, 200, 200);    
   }

   var dataImg = this.refs.canvas.toDataURL();
   console.log(dataImg);
}


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref="canvas" width={200} height={200}> </canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It actually converts image to canvas but the `toDataURL` generates blank data image. I wanted to convert generated canvas to base64 data image. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the `toDataURL()` inside the `onload` handler. Right now `toDataURL()` is executed before the image has been drawn, hence the blank image.

You also want to consider using a callback/promise after obtaining the data-url as the call is asynchronous, and if you intend to pass the data-url to some other function.

In addition you need to keep track of scope, either as shown below referencing `this` before the call, or you can use `bind()` on the callback handler.

```
var me = this; // keep reference for inner call
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 600, 600,       // `this` is now image
                        0, 0, 200, 200);
    // this line needs to go here
    var dataImg = me.refs.canvas.toDataURL(); // note `me` being used here
    console.log(dataImg);
    // consider a callback to pass result to next function in chain
};
// set src last
img.src = url;
```

Comment: yea tried that, throws error 'canvas' of undefined, but if I wrap 'toDataURL' inside of a settimeout function it works, thanks

Comment: @JohnnyDerp don't use setTimeout - that will likely fail at some point (slow connection, disk etc.). I updated with info on the scope issue.